# backgroundSize "cover" not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, background-image, fade

I am using the following to load a ramdom  background image each time the browser is refreshed. On top I use 2 z-layers that fade in, one from black to trasparent and another a overlay pattern from transparent to solid. Works fine on Chrome and Safari but Firefox refuses to fade out layer no1 (black to transpartent), and also Firefox refuses to strech the images to cover the background.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var totalCount = 6;
function ChangeIt() 
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.background = 'images/'+num+'.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
}
</script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#000">
 <a style="display:block; position:fixed; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; cursor:pointer" href="#/">
<div class="overlay fade-out one">
</div>
<div class="overlaygrid">
</div>
</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
ChangeIt();
</script> 
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
.fade-out {
opacity:1; 
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 0;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 0;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 0;

-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;

}

.fade-out.one {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.0s;
animation-delay: 0.0s;
}



.overlay {display:block;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%; background:#000; z-index:1 }

.overlaygrid {display:block;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%; background: url('../assets/bg-overlay-pattern.png'); z-index:2}
```

Comment: A JSFiddle would do wonders here

Comment: does this help? http://vuerichb.cc/

Comment: No, it doesn't, but here, I made a fiddle for you. If you can make it work to show your pictures and the issue, maybe we can do more: http://jsfiddle.net/Krv3P/

Comment: Sorry I'm not very used to jsfiddle.. I corrected the path for the overlay-pattern and removed <div class="overlay fade-out one"></div>
now it shows the pictures. Do you see it?

Comment: In order to see the issues, you need to update the fiddle with the 'Update' link at the top and post the new link, likely all it did was add a /1 or something to the end

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tomtom/Krv3P/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure to add the following CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** If body doesn't have a background already, you can set the background-size via the CSS without having to reset it via JavaScript.  Keeps the JS manipulation to a minimum. Same goes for any styling property (except of course your image...unless you want to have a default image).

Comment: cheers technophobia, now all I have to do is figure out why my fading div gets stuck :)